# How can I convert a ECDSA curve specification from the SEC2 form into the form needed by Go?

Tags: cryptography, standards, go, elliptic-curve

I`m trying to implement ECDSA in the curve secp256k1 in Google Go.

Secp256k1 is defined by the SECG standard (SEC 2, part 2, [Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters over <sub>p</sub>](http://www.secg.org/collateral/sec2_final.pdf), page 15) in terms of parameters p, a, b, G compressed, G uncompressed, n and h.

In [Go's crypto library](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#Curve), the curves are defined by parameters P, N, B, Gx, Gy and BitSize. How do I convert parameters given by SECG into the ones needed by Go?

Comment: I'm assuming you were asking this question for a Bitcoin implementation... how did you end up solving this issue (I see go's implementation wasn't compatible with bit coin)

Comment: @makerofthings7 - https://github.com/ThePiachu/Golang-Koblitz-elliptic-curve-DSA-library - I grabbed the original ECDSA libraries and changed the necessary curve parameters and curve equations to match the specifications. This library is for example powering Vanity Pool (https://vanitypool.appspot.com/) and my testing suite (http://gobittest.appspot.com/) - both produce addresses compatible with Bitcoin. I haven't tested the message signing, but I think someone else made a client using this library, so it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `elliptic` package of Go,

> A `Curve` represents a short-form Weierstrass curve with a=-3.

So, we have curves of the form `y² = x³ - 3·x + B` (where both `x` and `y` take values in <sub>P</sub>). `P` and `B` thus are the parameters to identify a curve, the others are only necessary for the operations on the curve elements which will be used for cryptography.

The SECG standard SEC 2 defines the secp256k1 curve as `y² = x³ + a·x + b` with a = 0, i.e. effectively `y² = x³ + b`.

These curves are not the same, independent of which b and B are selected here.

**Your conversion is not possible with the `elliptic` package's `Curve` class**, as it only supports some special class of curves (these with `a = -3`), while SEC 2 recommends curves from other classes (a = 0 for the `...k1` curves).

---

On the other hand, the curves with `...r1` in the name seem to have `a = -3`. And actually, `secp256r1` seems to be the same curve which is available in `elliptic` as `p256()`. (I didn't prove this, but at least some the hex digits of the uncompressed form of the base point in SEC 2 are the coordinates of the base point in elliptic.)

Comment: secp256r1 is the same curve than NIST's P-256, defined in [FIPS 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf). The Go crypto library is documented to implement P-256.